# Difference Android client / Thin client

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, restlet, objectify

I'm trying to make a Client for my restlet server deployed on Google App Engine.
By following this tutorial : http://www.tutos-android.com/webservice-rest-android-appengine-restlet-objectify I was able to do an Android client.
Can I port it to a "Fat Client" ? (I just copyed/pasted the code but it seems not working)
What is the difference between an Android Client and "Fat Client" (I hope this is the good term in english) ?

It seems like I'm sending a Null object (server side : nullpointerexception while parsing).

PS : I'm using Objectify 4 Framework on the restlet server.

Thank's for your responses ! :)

ERRATUM : 
I didn't mean "Fat client", with @Baalthasarr 's answer I can understand that I said something wrong. 
 Both of Swing client i'm trying to make and Android client are "THIN client", they only communicate with the server to get some datas..

The question is : Is there a difference to make those clients to communication with the server ? (the android client works perfectly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose an Android Client is just a Client that run on Android.

You can for example difference between "Fat Client" and "Thin Client"
The difference is, that a "Fat client" has some logic implemented while a "Thin Client" has only methods to display the results, but all calculations are made on the Server site.

- Thin Client = Client with less code, only nessesary code to display something
- Fat Client = like Thin client but has some logic implemented so it could e.g work without a Server

Your Android Client can be either a "Fat Client" or an "Thin Client".

Comment: Thank's for a so quick answer.
I didn't know that they were "thin client" too. I Need to edit my question, Give me a few sec !

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.. Their both and java client..
Android is based on Java with addition of android frameWork.

My guess will be that you forgot something with the communication between the server of you forgot to make the object you are trying pass as Serialzable which is necessery in case of passing object in the network

Comment: Thank's for answering ! :)
I did check the code twice. And I didn't notice any difference. 
Do you want me to post some code, or do you have any clue to pass the object as "Serialzable" ? :)

Comment: In order to make object Serializable you just need to add the Object you want to pass: class MyObject implements Serializable.
If it won't work attach the code that tried to communicate from Java Client an Android and the Object definition of you class you want to pass